# Flutter/net core/signalr Trying to get two clients to navigate to a page together

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, websocket, signalr

I have everything correctly setup in my program.cs on backend correct url names etc but I cannot get both clients to navigate to the page when testing locally with two different browsers using websockets over http/ws

MatchMakingController.cs

```
 [HttpPost("joinQueue")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> JoinQueue([FromBody] JoinQueueModel model)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("1: JoinQueue called");
     int playerCharacterId = model.PlayerCharacterId;
     // Check if player is already in queue to prevent duplicates
     if (!matchmakingQueue.Contains(playerCharacterId))
     {
         matchmakingQueue.Add(playerCharacterId);
     }

     // Try to match players if there are at least 2 in the queue
     if (matchmakingQueue.Count >= 2)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("2: Matchmaking logic processing");
         int player1Id = matchmakingQueue[0];
         int player2Id = matchmakingQueue[1];
         matchmakingQueue.RemoveRange(0, 2); // Remove matched players from the queue

         var match = new Match
         {
             Player1ID = player1Id,
             Player2ID = player2Id,
             Status = "in progress"
         };

         _context.Matches.Add(match);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         // Inside your JoinQueue method, after saving the match
         await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("MatchFound", new { matchId = match.MatchID, player1Id, player2Id });

         return Ok(new { matchId = match.MatchID, player1Id, player2Id });
     }

     return Ok(new { message = "Waiting for an opponent..." });
 }
```

Frontend signalR

```
late HubConnection _hubConnection;
  final String serverUrl = "http://localhost:5111/battleHub";
  final void Function(int matchId, int player1Id, int player2Id) onMatchFound;

  SignalRService({required this.onMatchFound}) {
    // Now a named parameter
    _hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(serverUrl).build();
    initConnection();
  }

  Future<void> initConnection() async {
    if (_hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
      try {
        await _hubConnection.start();
        print("Connection Started");
        _setupListeners();
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error starting connection: ${e.toString()}");
      }
    }
  }

  void _setupListeners() {
    _hubConnection.on('MatchFound', (arguments) {
      print('MatchFound event received');
      if (arguments != null && arguments.length >= 3) {
        final int matchId = arguments[0] as int;
        final int player1Id = arguments[1] as int;
        final int player2Id = arguments[2] as int;
        onMatchFound(matchId, player1Id, player2Id);
      }
    });
  }
```

Api

```
Future<MatchmakingResponse?> joinMatchmakingQueue(
      int playerCharacterId) async {
    print('Joining queue with playerCharacterId: $playerCharacterId');
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:5111/api/matchmaking/joinQueue'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({'playerCharacterId': playerCharacterId}),
    );

    print('Response body1: ${response.body}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      // Adjusted to return a MatchmakingResponse object
      return MatchmakingResponse.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      print(
          'Failed to join matchmaking queue. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<MatchDetails> fetchMatchDetails(
      int matchId, int requesterCharacterId) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'http://localhost:5111/api/matchmaking/match/$matchId/details/$requesterCharacterId'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return MatchDetails.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load match details');
    }
```

Lobby page with button to enter game

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _signalRService =
        SignalRService(onMatchFound: (matchId, player1Id, player2Id) {
      _navigateToBattleScreen(matchId, player1Id, player2Id);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _signalRService.closeConnection();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _fetchCharacterDetails() async {
    try {
      final fetchedCharacter = await ApiService()
          .fetchPlayerCharacterDetails(widget.playerCharacterId);
      setState(() {
        _latestCharacterDetails =
            fetchedCharacter; // Update state with the latest character details
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error fetching character details: $e");
    }
  }

  void _navigateToBattleScreen(int matchId, int player1Id, int player2Id) {
    print('Am i trying to navigate?');
    int opponentCharacterId =
        (widget.playerCharacterId == player1Id) ? player2Id : player1Id;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BattlePvPScreen(
                  playerCharacter: widget.character,
                  matchId: matchId,
                  opponentCharacterId: opponentCharacterId,
                )));
  }


ElevatedButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                    label: Text('Battle PvP'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final matchmakingResponse = await ApiService()
                          .joinMatchmakingQueue(
                              widget.character.playerCharacterId);

                      if (matchmakingResponse != null &&
                          matchmakingResponse.matchId != null) {
                        // Determine the opponent's character ID
                        int opponentCharacterId =
                            matchmakingResponse.player1Id ==
                                    widget.character.playerCharacterId
                                ? matchmakingResponse.player2Id!
                                : matchmakingResponse.player1Id!;

                        // Navigate to BattlePvPScreen
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BattlePvPScreen(
                              playerCharacter: widget.character,
                              matchId: matchmakingResponse.matchId!,
                              opponentCharacterId: opponentCharacterId,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        // Handle waiting or error
                        print("Waiting for an opponent or an error occurred.");
                      }
                    },
```

I'm still new to development so please excuse me if I've made silly mistakes or missed anything I'm happy to post any additional information as necessary. One player is navigated for now but that's because of the nav push on the button not listening to the matchfound event correctly and navigating due to that from signal service.

DEBUG OUTPUT

```
Response Body: {"playerCharacterId":58,"playerId":27,"characterId":1,"health":105,"damage":25,"armour":10,"level":6,"experience":10,"wins":6,"losses":0,"player":null,"character":{"characterId":1,"name":"Mage","damage":20,"health":80,"level":1,"experience":0,"armour":5}}
Connection Started
Joining queue with playerCharacterId: 58
MatchFound event received
Response body1: {"matchId":65,"player1Id":61,"player2Id":58}
```

I tried to navigate both players based on player1id player2id and matchid to the game after listening to the matchfound event received

Comment: This has been fixed

The issued lied in this

void _setupListeners() {
    _hubConnection.on('MatchFound', (arguments) {
      print('MatchFound event received');
      if (arguments != null && arguments.length >= 3) {
        final int matchId = arguments[0] as int;
        final int player1Id = arguments[1] as int;
        final int player2Id = arguments[2] as int;
        onMatchFound(matchId, player1Id, player2Id);
      }
    });
  }

As args came in as a map with 3 arguments inside it it failed my check for whether there were three arguments. Oops..